# Unable to patch the state with update to the store using NGXS. I keep seeing type error: cannot freeze

Tags: javascript, angular, state, ngxs, angular11

I'm working with a basic Angular 11 application which has authentication implemented (using AWS Cognito & Amplify). What I'm trying to do here is quite simple. I am using builtin AWS Amplify methods to do the authentication. I am using NGXS to store the auth related items like tokens, user info etc.

```
import { State, Action, StateContext, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';
import { AuthStateModel, defaultAuthState } from './auth.model';
import {
  LoginAction,
  AuthenticationCheckAction,
  LogoutAction,
} from './auth.actions';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { updateItem } from '@ngxs/store/operators';

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: 'authState',
  defaults: defaultAuthState,
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthState {
  cognitoClientId = environment.cognitoClientId;
  cognitoCallbackURL = environment.cognitoCallbackURL;
  cognitoDomainName = environment.cognitoDomainName;
  loginurl = `https://${this.cognitoDomainName}/login?response_type=code&client_id=${this.cognitoClientId}&redirect_uri=${this.cognitoCallbackURL}`;

  @Selector()
  static getIsLoggedIn(state: AuthStateModel) {
    console.log('from getIsLoggedIn selector =>', state);
    return state.isLoggedIn;
  }

  @Action(LoginAction)
  login() {
    window.location.assign(this.loginurl);
  }

  @Action(AuthenticationCheckAction)
  checkLogin({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    const state = getState();
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((currentUser) => {
        const isLoggedIn = true;
        const username = currentUser?.attributes?.name;
        patchState({
          currentUser,
          isLoggedIn,
          username,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    return;
  }

  @Action(LogoutAction)
  logout({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    Auth.signOut()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        patchState(defaultAuthState);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    return;
  }
}
```

Everything works except when it hits the patchState method inside the checkLogin function, it throws the following error in the browser console.:-

```
TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (ngxs-store.js:1869)
    at ngxs-store.js:1884
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (ngxs-store.js:1874)
    at ngxs-store.js:1884
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (ngxs-store.js:1874)
    at ngxs-store.js:1884
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Curiously, the error is gone if I comment out the mention of `currentUser` from the pathState() method. So it is the update of the object inside the state that is problematic.

The line referenced in this error of the ngxs-store.js file contains the following code. The line at 1869 is the Object.freeze(o) one at the beginning:-

```
const deepFreeze = (/**
 * @param {?} o
 * @return {?}
 */
(o) => {
    Object.freeze(o);
    /** @type {?} */
    const oIsFunction = typeof o === 'function';
    /** @type {?} */
    const hasOwnProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach((/**
     * @param {?} prop
     * @return {?}
     */
    function (prop) {
        if (hasOwnProp.call(o, prop) &&
            (oIsFunction ? prop !== 'caller' && prop !== 'callee' && prop !== 'arguments' : true) &&
            o[prop] !== null &&
            (typeof o[prop] === 'object' || typeof o[prop] === 'function') &&
            !Object.isFrozen(o[prop])) {
            deepFreeze(o[prop]);
        }
    }));
    return o;
});
```

Not savvy enough to understand what's going on here. This is a simple attempt to patch the state. The state model is as follows:-

```
export class AuthStateModel {
  isLoggedIn: Boolean;
  currentUser: Object;
  username: String;
}

export const defaultAuthState: AuthStateModel = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  currentUser: {},
  username: '',
};
```

Is there anything I can do to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when I run into an issue like this, where I can't change an object, I just clone it. I typically use lodash's cloneDeep for this:

```
patchState({
  currentUser: _.cloneDeep(currentUser),
  isLoggedIn,
  username,
});
```

Also, try to keep your state serializable. Not familiar with AWS Cognito & Amplify, but if the currentUser is an object that has methods and other members tied to it that is needed for later, then I wouldn't store the currentUser object in state.

Comment: You're right about not wanting to store an object with built-in methods. I am way better off just pulling the pertinent details and storing them in the store rather than dumping non-essential junk. Thanks!