# Angular NGXS TypeError: Cannot freeze

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngxs

[image]

The code that dispatches the action

```
  constructor(auth: AuthService, private store: Store) {
    this.userAuth = auth.signedIn.subscribe({ next: (user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.store.dispatch(new SetUser(user));
    }});
  }
```

The actions definition

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export class SetUser {
  static readonly type = '[firebase.User | null] Add';

  constructor(public payload: firebase.User | null) {}
}
```

And my store implementation:

```
    @Action(SetUser)
    add({ patchState }: StateContext<UserStateModel>, { payload }: SetUser): void {
        patchState({
            user: payload
        });
    }
@State<UserStateModel>({
    name: 'user',
    defaults: {
        user: null
    }
})
```

Comment: Implementation details are missing.  You need to provide an example where the error is reproduced. Try stackblitz.

Comment: @VictorLuchian I cannot use stackblitz exposing a firebase project. I think every implementation detail is clear here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to patch the state with update to the store using NGXS. I keep seeing type error: cannot freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884199/unable-to-patch-the-state-with-update-to-the-store-using-ngxs-i-keep-seeing-typ)

Answer (score 1):

Make `static readonly type = '[firebase.User | null] Add';` non-static, like so:

`static type = '[firebase.User | null] Add';`

Since we can't see your whole code (e.g. you post some constructor without any class around) and you won't let us (see comments), that's my best guess following the error-message complaining about some readonly property.

Otherwise there might be some readonly properties in `firebase.User`, how about that?

You insert something in the store that NGXS is trying to freeze. "Freezing" involves some kind of overwriting which is not allowed on readonly properties. Now it's on you to find what's readonly in there in case my two hints above didn't help.